# SSL Certificate Errors authenticating AutoDesk-Forge on Kubernetes cluster

Tags: node.js, ssl, kubernetes, dns, autodesk-forge

We have a web application deployed with kubernetes, and recently (week of 8/9/21) we suddenly started having errors using the forge API.  Everything works as expected in our development environment (just using Docker containers, no kubernetes).

We're using an older forge api (the forge-apis npm package; we plan on upgrading to autodesk.forge.designautomation but simply don't have the time/resources right now).

We're primarily using the model derivative API, but the issues may all be related to the authentication step:

```
const oAuth = new ForgeSDK.AuthClientTwoLegged(config.forgeClientId, config.forgeClientSecret, [
  'data:read',
  'data:write',
  'data:create',
  'bucket:read',
  'bucket:create'],
   true)
token = await oAuth.authenticate()
```

Many times, this will fail with the following error:

> Error [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID]: Hostname/IP does not match
> certificate's altnames: Host: developer.api.autodesk.com. is not in
> the cert's altnames: DNS:*.beta.doxo.com, DNS:beta.doxo.com
> at Object.checkServerIdentity (tls.js:288:12)
> at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1485:27)
> at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:321:20)
> at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:918:8)
> at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:688:12) {   reason: "Host: developer.api.autodesk.com. is not in the cert's altnames:
> DNS:*.beta.doxo.com, DNS:beta.doxo.com",   host:
> 'developer.api.autodesk.com',   cert: {
> subject: [Object: null prototype] { CN: '*.beta.doxo.com' },
> issuer: [Object: null prototype] {
> C: 'US',
> O: 'Amazon',
> OU: 'Server CA 1B',
> CN: 'Amazon'
> },
> subjectaltname: 'DNS:*.beta.doxo.com, DNS:beta.doxo.com',
> infoAccess: [Object: null prototype] {
> 'OCSP - URI': [Array],
> 'CA Issuers - URI': [Array]
> }

However, not always. Sometimes it will make it to various later steps (e.g. creating a storage bucket via the BucketsAPI, uploading to the bucket, or converting the file to SVF).  It seems totally random how far it will make it, and typically hang at one of these steps and stop receiving a response until our connection timeout error throws.

Sometimes when it makes it to the SVF conversion step it will throw a different certificate-related error:

> Error: SSL Certificate error: ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
> at NavigatorWatcher.waitForNavigation (/opt/model_service/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/NavigatorWatcher.js:76:20)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
> at async Page.goto (/opt/model_service/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:465:19)

Other times, during the SVG conversion it will throw a JSON circular reference error, again related to the certificate:

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON    --> starting at
> object with constructor 'Object'   --- property 'issuerCertificate'
> closes the circle   at JSON.stringify ()

My best assessment so far is there is an issue with the kubernetes DNS - but I can't figure out why 1) this would suddenly start occurring (this has been otherwise stable for several years) and 2) why the behavior seems somewhat random.

Any input much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We did move to TLS 1.2 on Dec 2018 ([see more info here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/upcoming-forge-system-upgrade-tls-12-upgrade-date-moved-oct-31)), can you confirm your app & environment are set for that?

Also, from time to time we have to renew the certification, is it possible that your environment is keeping old certificates in cache?